# Not running the solidity smart contract of splitting the transaction money?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ether

code link:
  https://github.com/0xcaff/splitter-contract/blob/master/contracts/Splitter.sol

Getting output:

```
   creation of SplitBalance errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address (arg="", type="string", value="")
```

How to do overcome this error and need to run the code.

Answer (score 2):

It is saying that the creation of the contract did not occur. The contract name is not what is posted in the Github link. Are you sure that code corresponds to that error.

As a note, that error is received when you not correctly pass in arguments to the function/constructor. `Error: invalid address (arg="", type="string", value="")` is saying that you are trying to pass in an address, but have done so incorrectly. When passing in an address to a function/constructor, it must be a string so you must wrap it with `""`.

If you are deploying this on remix, you will include `0x123...` as the address argument.

Comment: How are you supposed to get a contract address if the address is not yet deployed / just a repo on Github?